# Is there any Radio grop button in .net winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

There is option called checkedListBox1 for check box group item..

Like that any control for radio button. and how to bind my data(data set) in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing for radio buttons. You may, however, look for third party controls or extend the existing `CheckedListBox` so that only one item at a time can be checked.

The second solution is a bit ugly, because seeing check boxes the user would expect to be allowed to select more than one option.

Answer (score 1):

User container to have same functionality as like group name.

container can be group box or Panel

Answer (score 0):

Put the radio buttons in their own panel, and they will work together, with only one button in the panel being selectable.

As for data-binding, there are several approaches available, such as creating a form Boolean property for each option, and binding each radio button to its property.

An easier approach would be to use Jay Andrew Allen's [RadioPanel](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20253/RadioPanel-Binding-RadioButton-Groups-to-Enumerati), which takes care of binding the radio button options to an enumeration field.